# Convert resource/stream to File

Tags: java

How can I do this?

```
File myFile = getFile(this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"))
```

OR

```
File myFile = getFile(this.getClass.getResource("test.txt"))
```

What code will I write in `getFile()` method?

Comment: Use BufferedReader? Or any better idea?

Comment: Classpath resources are usually not files (outside development) so you would need to ensure the file isn't packaged in an archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can do it as

```
    File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("test.txt").toURI());
    System.out.println(f);
```

output (my Eclipse test)

```
D:\workspace1\x\target\classes\text.txt
```

but it will not work always. What if your resource is in a jar? You will get

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

Comment: is there any way to make it work inside the jar as well?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the function:

```
public File getFile(FileInputStream inStream){

File file =new File("file.txt");
OutputStream outStream = null;
outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }


            outStream.close();

return file;

}
```

Comment: FileOutputStream will first write it to the location provided by File?

Comment: `FileOutputStream`will open a stream to the file pointed by absolute path mentioned in constructor of `File`. You can pass this as a function argument to avoid hardcoding.